# Closure is injective on irreducible closed sets + ambiguity in proposition

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

This may be a very simple question about "written-math" but as a non-english speaker it maker the following proposition difficult to understand

**Proposition.** Let $X$ be a topological space. If $U$ is an open set of $X$ then the map $Y\mapsto\overline{Y}$, restricted to closed irreducible sets $Y$ in $U$ is injective

The sets $Y$ are $X$-closed or $U$-closed (very different things since $U$ is open)?. Is there an established "semantic" difference between closed sets *in* $U$ and closed sets *of* $U$?

I assume the closure is the $X$-closure because there is no indication to do otherwise. Then the sets $Y$ should be $U$-closed for the closure to be a non-trivial map. Then why use $U$ open set *of* $X$ but $Y$ closed *in* $U$?

So let $Y,Z\subseteq U$ be closed sets (of/in? $U$) such that $\overline{Y}=\overline{Z}$. Then $Y=Y_1\cap U$ and $Z=Z_1\cap U$ for $Y_1,Z_1$ closed sets of $X$
$$Z\subseteq\overline{Z}=\overline{Y}=\overline{Y_1\cap U}\subseteq Y_1\cap\overline{U}\subseteq Y_1$$
$$Z=Z\cap U\subseteq Y_1\cap U=Y$$
And $Y\subseteq Z$ for the same reason so $Y=Z$. Is this proof correct?

Thanks

Comment: What is $V$? $Z$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry they are the same

Comment: Where do you use that $Y$ and $Z$ are closed *irreducible*? Btw, what does it mean?

Comment: @Berci good point i do not use it. A set is irreducible if it cannot be written as the union of two proper closed subsets of it

Comment: @Berci I think the irreducibility hypothesis is not needed. I included it because i didnt know but the proposition here is part of a bigger proposition concerning irreducible sets and a bijection. this comes after proving that if $Y$ is irreducible then so is $\overline{Y}$

Comment: Moreover, neither the *openness* of $U$ is used. Nevertheless, your proof looks correct at first sight..

Comment: And your interpretation about closures is also correct.

Comment: @Berci Thanks for checking. The openness is there for the same reason, it is used in the larger proposition (about an inverse map of the closure)